# java.io.IOException: 42-Error in HTTP operation in J2me

Tags: http, java-me

I am developing a mobile application in J2me for Nokia Asha 305, which will connect a webservice (WCF restful service).

Connecting from SIM 2 is working fine but while I am trying to connect SIM 1 it throw following exception

```
java.io.IOException: 42-Error in HTTP operation
```

Comment: I'm trying too to develop an app except is for Nokia Asha 302, but close models, and I get the same error. Could be the lack of credit? I have 6 MB of traffic left though. Did you find out the answer?